# Уникализация массива

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив из двух элементов такого вида:

```
Array
(
    [0] => **.jpg
    [1] => 4
    [2] => **.jpg
    [3] => 4
    [4] => **.jpg
    [5] => 4
    [6] => **.jpg
    [7] => 4
)
```

Нужно уникализировать только строчки с фото, не трогая другие элементы, как это можно сделать?

Comment: **[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php)**  либо **[array_map](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-map.php)**. В зависимости от того, что значит `уникализировать только строчки с фото`

Comment: все с расширением jpg будут?

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = ["**.jpg", 4, "**.jpg",  4, "**.jpg",  4, "**.jpg", 4];

$imgs = [];
foreach($array as $row)
{
    if (is_string($row))
    {
        $imgs[] = $row;
    }
}

print_r(array_unique($imgs));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно регуляркой выборку сделать

```
<?php

$array= [
 1,2,3,4,  "**.jpg", "***.jpg", "adfasdf.png", 7,5, "qwerty"
];

$images = array_filter($array,  function ($value) {
    return  preg_match("/.jpg|.png$/", $value);
}) ;


var_dump($images);
```